# Why is "U.S." abbreviated as "EE. UU." if it is singular?

Tags: traducción

The United States of America, the USA, the United States, the U.S. are all singular nouns unless in the possessive. Why does the Spanish abbreviation for the U.S., los EE. UU., include the doubled letters if it is a singular noun?

Comment: Of interest, about the English usage of _United States_ as a singular noun: http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002663.html

Comment: You've answered yourself in the question: why did you use the plural article *los* if it is a singular noun? Because it is plural, of course.

Comment: Because "states" is plural.

Comment: But I heard lots of times **`Estados Unidos tiene un déficit comercial ···`**, when the name of the country (*Estados Unidos*) is replacing a noun syntagm(?) such as `ese país`: ***Ese país** ha incumplido el tratado* `==>` ***Estados Unidos** ha incumplido el tratado*

Answer (score 4):

In Spanish, one doubles the letter of an abbreviation if it refers to more than one object.

For example, if I reference page 9, I would write *p. 9*. But if I were to reference page**s** 9 through 12, I would write *pp. 9-12* because there is more than one page.

In Spanish we write *los EE.UU.* for the same reason: **los** Estado**s** Unido**s** is plural, so we double the letters in the abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I understand the question... In Spanish we say *Estados Unidos* (both noun and adjective plural), so it's only normal that it is EE. UU.

You can see more here: http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/ee-uu-eua-usa-us/

Comment: My guess is he's questioning why we consider it plural, if it often agrees as singular when the subject of a sentence: (Los) Estados Unidos investigará, dejó, es, etc, in comparison to, for instance, (Las) Filipinas investigarán, dejaron, son, etc.  My guess is there's a mental elision/imagination of "El país/estado de…" for the former, and a strong memory of "Las islas" in the latter.